# One extra position on front derailleur besides trim

Tags: derailleur, shifting

After I changed shift cables, I have 4 positions on my front derailleur. WTF?

I have a double chainring. I have a trim position as well, but after shifting to the big chainring, I can still move the STI lever a tiny amount. If I do so, the derailleur will click into a 4th position and the derailleur moves out a tiny amount. From there I can downshift back to the 3rd position.

This only appeared after I changed gear cables and fiddled around with the limit screw. What should I do?

Comment: Can you please quote the model of your left shifter?  Could be its a double/triple combo, and you've adjusted it by accident when replacing the shift cable?

Comment: @Criggie Any way of checking it? I bought it as a second hand bike, so I don't know the model. Ultegra, bike was originally purchased in 2014. Chainring is SG-x 50-F if that's of any help.

Comment: Derailleur is FD-6700. Looking at photos of ST-6700, it looks like that.

Comment: Perhaps a better question is, which front shifter do you have? The shifter positions and trim are controlled by the shifter, not the derailleur. If it is a st-6800 it will have 4 positions - low, low trim, top trim, top. Not sure about earlier series such as the st-6700.

Comment: Oh apparently the ST-6700 has 2 trim positions as well. Maybe the previous cable was so tight that it didn't allow going into the final position?

Comment: @LordZsolt that is possible. There is a whole adjustment procedures to setup the trim correctly so maybe that hadn't been done.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it is a further trim position if you have double (not triple) shifters, and previously the limit screw was preventing the cable movement. Now you’ve installed a new cable and changed limit screws a bit maybe you’ve allowed access to a high gear trim position.

My 105 5700 double shifter does the same thing, and I can prevent it from happening by tightening the high limit screw

Comment: Yeah, it was this. The Shifter actually has 2 trim positions. A combination of adjusting the cable tension and limit screw allowed me to eliminate the last position. Wondering if I should leave it like that? The chain doesn't rub and the cable still  has a tiny bit of flex when I move it by hand. Or is it bad to leave so much cable tension?

Comment: @LordZsolt if it’s set up to shift then it’s working, it’s up to you if you want the second trim and obviously have the skills to choose. As for the cable tension, if you mean in the big ring, that’s just normal, the tension comes from the shifter